# without moving next activity Send data from another activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity, message-passing

In this code I want to send firstname and middlename to another activity. But My problem is that without clicking any button I want to send these two values to the next activity.
Because in this activity, clicking on the send button, data should be passed to the next Activity, but the screen should not navigate to the next activity.
Now These Two values I want to access in some another class file.

Can any one please help me.

**class**

```
 Send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {             
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                 String first_name = fname1.getText().toString();
                 String middle_name = mname1.getText().toString();
 }   
        });
```

Comment: You can create a class for all constants or for temporary data and assign ur username and password values to that so that you can access those credentials from other class :D

Comment: can you please provide me some example for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with `SQLite`, `Shared Preferences` or simply just by create a new public class with `static` variables. 
Create a new class :

```
public class Global {
    public static String first_name = "";
    public static String middle_name = "";
}
```

Change your code :

```
 Send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {             
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                 Global.first_name = fname1.getText().toString();
                 Global.middle_name = mname1.getText().toString();
 }   
        });
```

Comment: Hi shall inilize all the values to null in Global.class

Comment: Global class firstname to final it cannot access from other classes

Comment: @user sorry it should be static only, not final

Comment: Global.middle_name like this I want to access the firstname

Comment: @user yes :) just call "Global.first_name" if u want to access the name

Comment: I want to access the this field means  Global.first_name it enough for this

Comment: @user you welcome :) Yes, if you want to do only that..sqlite and shared pref is a little bit overkill. But feel free to upvote other answers, since their answer is also true.

Comment: String first_name =fname1.setText(Global.first_name); like this I am accessing firstname it showing cannot convert void to String this errror

Comment: @user no, just use fname1.setText(Global.first_name); to display the text or String first_name = Global.first_name if u want to insert it to a variable.

Comment: Which method I have to use setText or getText Because I displaying that same value in another activity

Comment: @user what do u want to do? If u want to get the text from the edittext then use getText, like String first_name =fname1.getText().toString();. U need to learn the basic of setting and getting String on edittext.

Comment: @user what do u want to do? If u want to get the text from the edittext then use getText, like String first_name =fname1.getText();. U need to learn the basic of setting and getting String on edittext.

Comment: The point is, just use Global.first_name to access the String. After that, you can do anything with that String

Comment: frist_name1.setText(Global.first_name); like this I wrote but it showing Null

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class for all constants or for temporary data and assign ur username and password values to that so that you can access those credentials from other class

```
public class Constants
{

    public static String F_Name = "fName";

    public static String M_Name = "mName";
}
```

and then assign values with

```
String FName = fname.getText().toString();
String MName = mname.getText().toString();
     Constants.F_Name = FName;
    Constants.M_Name = MName;
```

and then get those values in other class like

```
if (FirstName.equals(Constants.F_Name){
}
```

THose values will be set till your app is running

Comment: suppose that value are dynamic means?

Comment: See whenver u will get the values like in your case with String first_name = fname1.getText().toString(); assign those value to COnstant.FName = fname1; and then you can get this fname from any of your class with Constants.FName

Comment: @user you can also used sharedPrefs for this, but it will be saved even after you exit the app till you replace those values with some another, you can initialize global values with any random string or Simply String F_Name;

Answer (score 1):

Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store key and value pair. You can use throughout application even if app is not in foreground. You can check this [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm). Hope it helps solve your solution.

Answer (score 1):

First option:

```
Intent i=new Intent(context,SOMECLASSNAME.class);
i.putExtra("first_name", fname1.getText().toString());
i.putExtra("name", mname1.getText().toString());
context.startActivity(i);
```

Second option:
You can use shared preferences http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor.putString("first_name", fname1.getText().toString());
editor.putString("second_name", mname1.getText().toString());
editor.commit();
```

Comment: if I use intent means it will move to next activity